# avoiding dynamic_cast without increasing coupling

Tags: c++

Suppose I want to avoid `dynamic_cast` in the following code:

```
struct Base { ... stuff ... };
struct HasColor {
  virtual Color getColor() const = 0;
  virtual void setColor(Color) = 0;
};
struct Foo : public Base, public HasColor {
  ... implements HasColor methods
};

...

vector<Base*> collection;
...
for(auto element : collection) {
   if(auto hasColor = dynamic_cast<HasColor*>(element)) {
      hasColor->SetColor(myColor);
   }
}
```

One solution is to add a method to downcast:

```
struct Base {
  HasColor* toHasColor() { return nullptr; }
};
struct Foo : public Base, public HasColor {
  ...
  HasColor* toHasColor() { return this; }
};
```

But this means that `Base` needs to know about every `Has` interface, increasing coupling.

Let's try the visitor pattern:

```
struct BaseVisitor {
   void visitHasColor(HasColor& hasColor) = 0
};
struct Base {
   virtual void visit(BaseVisitor& visitor) = 0;
};
```

But we are left with the same issue: each `Has` class needs to be added to `BaseVisitor`, causing more coupling and more recompilation (this being C++, each modification to `Base` means waiting a few minutes).

This gets worse if I want to support plugins. A plugin cannot modify `Base` or `BaseVisitor`, so then plugins can't add additional `Has` classes. (I realize that typical C++ RTTI may not work well between libraries, however I've seen one custom RTTI system that does, and apparently the one in Qt does.)

**Can I avoid RTTI/`dynamic_cast` while keeping my code extensible?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580270/avoiding-dynamic-cast-rtti) seems similar. In my case, I'm open to other ways to represent my data in the first place.

(It is recommended to avoid `dynamic_cast` in C++ style guides such as [this one](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Run-Time_Type_Information__RTTI_).)

Comment: What about using an _interface_ in 1st place? To add extensions you might want to add more interfaces.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `Base` is an interface. What do you mean?

Comment: ATM we can see only `struct Base { ... stuff ... };`??

Comment: @Taylor `hasColor` should be an interface too.

Comment: the google style guide is targeted at the google code base. Wouldnt be the first time I see one of their suggestions that doesnt apply elsewhere. Dont follow them blindly

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Who said I'm following anything blindly?

Comment: I see no reason not to use `dynamic_cast` and the only thing you mention is that style guide.

Comment: @MartinBonner `HasColor` is an interface. Notice the pure virtuals.

Comment: You can avoid doing it explicitly by moving it into the base, hidden behind a function template that does the cast. I don’t think you can get rid of it completely without essentially implementing your own RTTI system.

Comment: i second molbdnilo, what you want is: Infer the type at runtime. This is rtti, so you either use it or end up building your own.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a collection of all kinds of things, some that are `HasColor` and others that aren't, then you must rely on `dynamic_cast` or similar RTTI in order to use the objects as `HasColor` or you must invert the dependency using visitor pattern, which introduces the coupling that is your problem.

A solution that does not require the use of `dynamic_cast` or other RTTI is to use a collection of only `HasColor` instances.

Comment: Do you consider the visitor pattern RTTI?